# Get real-time stocks data for displaying as well as for drawing graphs for my iPhone application

Tags: ios, stock

I'm looking for some data API for my stocks application which can be parsed. I want to use it for displaying data as well as drawing graphs purpose. I have seen other posts pointing to Yahoo or Google APIs etc, but haven't really got the idea how to use them.

Can anybody please point me to any guide which can be helpful?

Comment: "haven't really got the idea how to use them" this is why there are API docs. Is there any specific section which is not clear to you?

Comment: In addition, I recommend you split this into 2 questions: how to retrieve data from a web API, and how to draw graphs.  They are 2 different domains.

Comment: Thanx Shoban and phooze for trying to help. I found out this reference after searching for stocks data http://vikku.info/codetrash/Yahoo_Finance_Stock_Quote_API and http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/ for drawing graphs with Yahoo api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo is one source for Quotes, there are others (Google is your friend).

Core-plot (code.google.com) is very popular for drawing graphs on the iPhone.